# nvm uninstall doesn't actually uninstall the node version

Tags: node.js, nvm

So I'm trying to clear out older versions of node.js.

I start with:

```
$ nvm ls
      v0.10.30
      v4.2.3
->    v6.6.0
      system
```

I don't want the older versions, so I then do:

```
$ nvm uninstall 4.2.3
Uninstalled node v4.2.3
```

I then verify that it's done what I wanted, but it gives the *same* list of installed versions as before:

```
$ nvm ls
      v0.10.30
      v4.2.3
->    v6.6.0
      system
```

Specifically, `v4.2.3` is still there.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  Any other way to force the uninstall?  I'm using the Cloud 9 IDE.

Comment: as of May 2019, this appears to work fine.

Answer (score 137):

removing manually:

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node
sudo rm -rf v4.2.3/
```

Answer (score 73):

Remove by command

```
nvm uninstall <version> 
nvm uninstall v16.7.0
```

remove manually

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node
sudo rm -rf v16.7.0/
```

Answer (score 18):

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node
rm -Rf v4.2.3
```

Try clearing your cache

```
nvm cache clear
```

Answer (score 10):

nvm deactivate
then
nvm uninstall 4.2.3 or (version number)

it will work.

Comment: Using "nvm deactivate" first and then "nvm uninstall [version]" did the job.

Answer (score 7):

It works now, in nvm version 0.35.1. Or at least it worked for me.

If the node version we want to uninstall is the currently used one though, before uninstalling it we need to `nvm use` another version.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than running uninstall and deleting the directory from nvm, do the other way around.

- Navigate to the nvm directory

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node
```

- Run nvm install

```
nvm uninstall <version>
nvm uninstall v16.7.0
```

This will automatically uninstall the specific node version and also delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted my node version using:

```
nvm uninstall v12.22.12
```

Answer (score -1):

example1. bash shell.

```
nvm uninstall  19.*
```

example2. bash shell.

```
for i in {1..30}; do echo $i; nvm uninstall  $i.*; done
```