# Un-installed node, still "node -v" prints version of the node . How to fix it(how to remove node completely) ?

Tags: node.js, uninstallation, nvm

I installed node 10.0 . but I wanted to change it to 8.9 .

So, I uninstalled node with "brew uninstall node" .

It was executed without any error result. Then I tried to check "node -v" and still it shows me current version of the node is 10.0.

[image: uninstalled without any error, checking "node -v" shows it's still installed]

[image: tried uninstalling second time, shows an error]

I found so many other questions like this, but none of this explains why does it happen. [Is it fine to use solution given in this link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634954/nvm-uninstall-doesnt-actually-uninstall-the-node-version) .

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found after surfing for 30-40 minutes.

To change version of the node, just use "nvm use "

It is possible that you will get an error like , **"N/A: version "versionNumber -> N/A" is not yet installed "**

Then, you need to install that particular version using command, "**nvm install 8.9.0**", Once this is installed. you can confirm in the folder **ls ~/.nvm/versions/node** , it will show all the currently available node versions on your local system.

Now, if you want to change the currently using version of the node, just use the command "nvm use versionNumber".

Hope it helps everyone.